# Which version of NDK should I use with a Titanium Android module?

Tags: android, module, android-ndk, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

According to the [source](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/package.json#L22) and [wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+the+Android+NDK), Titanium requires r9 of the Android NDK. But in the [Android archives](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html), the oldest version available is r10e (May 2015). The current version is r14b.

With r14b (and r13b) I get compilation failures from ndk-build involving a C++ type mismatch.

`[ERROR] /Users/jdee/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.1.0.GA/android/native/include/AndroidUtil.h:57:49: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]`

I can compile a module cleanly using r10e, r11c and r12b, but I'm hesitant to release something with an unsupported NDK version. It seems strange that Titanium requires a version of NDK from 2014 as well. I'm not sure which version to use.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the same [wiki page](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+the+Android+NDK) speaks of NDK r12, which can be downloaded from the [official archive](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases). The drawbacks of using an older NDK are, outweighed by the risks of relying on tiny nuances of compiler compatibility. It would require exhaustive testing on a wide range of supported devices to prove that your build with NDK r16 is OK. And note that upgrading NDK  requires some fixes, see https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/9926.

As long as you don't need the native APIs that are specific for Oreo and higher, you can use r12 without fear.

If your project involves other NDK components that cannot be built with NDK r12, please remember that you can mix shared libraries built separately (with different NDK versions) in one app, as long as they do not share C++ objects between them. Titanium v8 framework is safe is this sense.

One point of weakness here is the shared STL runtime **libc++_shared.so**. You cannot have two different versions of it in your app. Probably the safest solution for such situation is to change the Titanium [**Application.mk** file](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/runtime/v8/Application.mk#L12) to use

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```